# Конвертация SCSS в SASS

Tags: вёрстка, sass, scss, map, препроцессор

Большой проект, написан на `SASS` и использованием синтаксиса `SASS`, а не `SCSS`. Поэтому изменить файл на `SCSS` не вариант, так как их очень много.

Нужно использовать ассоциативные массив(map) подобного вида:

```
$primary-colors: (
  "red":   "#ff0000",
  "green": "#00ff00",
  "blue":  "#0000ff"
);
```

Это синтаксис `SCSS`, а мне нужен `SASS`. На конструкцию такого вида компилятор ругается:

> Error: unclosed parenthesis
>
> on line 394 of style/_intro-val.sass
>
> $primary-colors: ( {    ----------------^

Как исправить написание? Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Может быть заменить скобку на какой-то другой символ или отступ определенный должен быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашла решение! Синтаксис SASS не поддерживает многострочность, это конечно портит простоту отладки кода и наглядность, однако проблема была решена вот так:

```
$primary-colors: ("red": "#ff0000", "green": "#00ff00", "blue": "#0000ff");
```

Возможно кому-то пригодится.